# What is a "repeat until success quantum circuit" in quantum neural networks?

Tags: quantum-gate, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, quantum-neural-network

I am working now on a quantum neural network project and want a deep explanation on the **Repeat Until Success circuit**.  What I know about this circuit is that it allows a nonlinear activation function to be applied by rotating around the $\hat y$ axis by an angle $\theta$. But I don't understand till now how this circuit works?  Can someone help me to clarify how it works?

Thank you

Comment: can you edit the post to add links to relevant references you've read on the topic?

Comment: It looks like you are asking about this paper here: https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.11240. Do you have any specific questions about it?

Answer (score 2):

A non-linear process involves a *measurement*. The idea of a repeat until success sequence is that when you do the measurement, one of the results will be the one you want. If you get it, great! You've succeeded. If the measurement result is not that answer that you were after, you know that you've not got what you want, and you should know how it's wrong. So, you have two choices. Sometimes, you can try and compensate for the incorrect measurement outcome (e.g. teleportation), which might include further non-linear steps. Sometimes, that's not an effective strategy. Instead, you just start again and hope for better luck next time. Either way, you keep going until you get the outcome you wanted.